# cURL not properly executing using code base in PHP

Tags: php

So I have used the following code when doing testing on the browser and it works great:

```
curl -X POST https://go.test.com/l/926923/2022-05-25/3l5rr
   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
   -d "926923_56554pi_926923_56554=Adam.Sem@test.com"
```

But when I go and convert it over to a PHP cURL request, it doesn't work properly as shown below:

```
$data = [
    '926923_56554pi_926923_56554' => 'Adam.Sem@test.com',
];
$postvars = http_build_query($data) . "\n";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://go.test.com/l/926923/2022-05-25/3l5rr');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

error_log(curl_getinfo($result));
error_log(print_r($result, true));

curl_close($curl);
```

Does anyone know what might be different from the first cURL request and the code version?

Comment: _it doesn't work properly_ is a bit vague. Please show the errors you receive.

Answer (score 0):

plese use your `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);` without `http_build_query` function.

like this:

```
$data = [
    '926923_56554pi_926923_56554' => 'Adam.Sem@test.com',
];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://go.test.com/l/926923/2022-05-25/3l5rr');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);

error_log(curl_getinfo($result));
error_log(print_r($result, true));

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: What about the `"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` do those need to be included as cURL headers? If so, how would I be able to do that?

Comment: i have edit my answer and insert the content type

Comment: CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS can be an array or a string so I don't think this changes anything